# What has to duplicate before cell enters M phase?

Tags: cell-biology, meiosis, cell, mitosis

What has to duplicate before cell enters M phase?

- DNA
- histones
- centrosome
- mitochondria (any other organelles?)
- condensins (not sure?)

have I forgotten anything?

Thank you in advance!